# Sequentially fitting Random Forest sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am training a Random Forest Classifier in python using sklearn on a corpus of image data. Because I am performing image segmentation I have to store the data of every pixel, which ends up being a huge matrix, like 100,000,000 long matrix of data points, and so when running a RF Classifier on that matrix, my computer gets a memory overflow error, and takes forever to run.

One Idea I had was to train the classifier on sequential small batches of the dataset, therefore eventually training on the whole thing but each time improving the fit of the classifier. Is this an idea that could work? Will the fit just override the last fit each time it is run?

Comment: Did you try resizing the images to lower resolution i.e. reducing drastically the number of pixels per image?

Comment: Yeah I'm reducing my images from their original resolution to 100x100 pixels.

Comment: I worked on a similar problem where the RFs acted on image patches (of lots of images). I constructed the trees separately on bootstrap samples of all the image patches (basically as much that I could fit into memory + room to create the model). I pickled each tree after fitting it. I had a script that only fit a single tree so that memory was released (not fitting all in a loop in a single script). After fitting all the trees I constructed the RF model by loading the trees manually.

Comment: @ChesterVonWinchester definitely seems time consuming but sounds like a good hacky workaround

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `warm_start` in order to pre-compute the trees:

```
# First build 100 trees on X1, y1
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, warm_start=True)
clf.fit(X1, y1)

# Build 100 additional trees on X2, y2
clf.set_params(n_estimators=200)
clf.fit(X2, y2)
```

Alternatively

```
def generate_rf(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test):
    rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=5, min_samples_leaf=3)
    rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    print "rf score ", rf.score(X_test, y_test)
    return rf

def combine_rfs(rf_a, rf_b):
    rf_a.estimators_ += rf_b.estimators_
    rf_a.n_estimators = len(rf_a.estimators_)
    return rf_a

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.33)
# Create 'n' random forests classifiers
rf_clf = [generate_rf(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test) for i in range(n)]
# combine classifiers
rf_clf_combined = reduce(combine_rfs, rfs)
```

Comment: This is helpful! If I use warm_start, can I set n_jobs=-1 to parallelize fitting and predicting?

Comment: In some documentation it states: "Setting the `warm_start` construction parameter to `True` disables support for parallelized ensembles but is necessary for tracking the OOB error trajectory during training."